# How to enable PowerApps & Dataverse for domain users?

Tags: microsoft-office, administration

The company I work for has PowerApps & Dataverse in its Office365 package, but it doesn't generally allow everyone to use it so its currently disabled. The IT would enable it for a couple of test users to play with it, but they don't know how and don't have time to look for it. They would however enable it for us if we told them what they need to click in order to assign us the required rights.

So, I was wondering if any of you knows if there is any Microsoft documentation explaining how to do it and could point me to that location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some licenses can use PowerApps, and there is no need to enable PowerApps. When PowerApps is included in the license, users can use them by default.

Comment: Oh! So it's a license _issue_ and not a privilege one :o I didn't expect this kind of plot twist.